How well can gene expression values be reconstructed?
I'm working some time on this question and I think there might be a limit which I can't overcome, but I'm curious what you think as I'm not that familiar with AI.
My aim is to create an embedding with AI models and to reconstruct the original data as well as possible from the embedding.
My data is the CCLE dataset with 16,383 gene expressions from 1037 cell lines.
I created two different models:

A Transformer model with MultiHeadAttention (MSELoss of 0.4)
A simple VAE (MSELoss of 0.6)

The 0.4 means that the value per position of the 16,383 gene expressions deviates by 0.4 from the original data.
I tried a lot with hyperparameters but I can't get below this value.
Do you think this can be the truth, or is there perhaps an even better way to create an embedding from which you can get the best possible reconstruction?

This question needs a lot more detail. What does the 0.4/0.6 value relate to? Are these gene counts (i.e. about half a gene count loss), log expression values, or some other value? How are you determining the accuracy / loss? Are you looking at the miRNA CCLE data, RPKM RNA Expression CCLE data, RSEM RNA Expression CCLE data, or the mutation call CCLE data (or something else)? [direct links would be helpful] Why are you asking about gene expression rather than isoform / transcript expression (which is the thing that is typically directly measured by sequencing)?
